# Default to IPv6 with WN722N - driver issue?

Tags: networking, drivers, ipv6

I connect to my dualstack router using a TP-Link WN722N v1 USB wifi stick. Both IPv4 and IPv6 work. However, IPv4 is preferred over IPv6. This is not only evident in all webbrowsers (e.g. all dualstack sites will be accessed using IPv4), but also nslookup uses IPv4 dns servers, and other software uses IPv4 over IPv6 as well.

I do not observe this issue on other machines in the same network. Could this be a driver issue? Does the driver really have that much influence over the different IP protocols?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check in the registry under key `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip6\Parameters` if the value `DisabledComponents` exists.

You may delete it (after saving) to restore the default situation.

([source](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/929852/guidance-for-configuring-ipv6-in-windows-for-advanced-users))

Comment: I changed it to 0x00 (as your link suggests) and that fixed it. Thanks!